# How to explode mutiple colulms using pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, explode

df=spark.sql("select key, name, subjects  from table")

df in from above select statement :

```
key name    subjects
12  x,y,z   1,2,3
20  a,b     8,7
```

df out :

```
12  x 1
12  y 2
12  z 3
20  a 8
20  b 7
```

tried converting to list , explode. Still throwing error. pls help the efficient way to achieve this ?

Comment: Related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53218931/how-to-unnest-explode-a-column-in-a-pandas-dataframe).

Answer (score 2):

One way using `pandas.DataFrame.apply`:

```
# df["name"] = df["name"].str.split(",")
# df["subjects"] = df["subjects"].str.split(",")
# If not already split

new_df = df.apply(pd.Series.explode)
print(new_df)
```

Output:

```
   key name subjects
0   12    x        1
0   12    y        2
0   12    z        3
1   20    a        8
1   20    b        7
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks chris. It is getting exploded. Still facing the error - Cannot reindex from a duplicate axis. Concat with ignore index is not working .Is it possible to generate temp unique indexes as key is duplicated during explode. pandasversion -1.0.5

```
df["name"] = df["name"].str.split(",") 
df["subjects"] = df["subjects"].str.split(",") 
new_df= df.apply(pd.Series.explode).reindex()
```